# Right align empty column (bash)?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have a script that is printing out columns, but if the left column is empty it won't align correctly.

Right now I am iterating over an array and printing out the key/value and using the `column` command to format the columns.  Below is what the code looks like.

```sh
# Code to make the array
declare -A pods
declare -A associative_array
pods=$(kubectl get pods | awk '{if(NR>1)print $1}')
for p in ${pods[*]}; do
    image=$(kubectl get pod "$p" -o json | jq -r '.spec.containers[].image')
    associative_array[$p]+="$image"
done

# Code to print the array
(printf "column1\tcolumn2\n"

for i in "${!associative_array[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$i" "${associative_array[$i]}"
done) | column -t -x
...
```

And here's an example of what the current output looks like.

```sh
column1                                           column2
prometheus-k8s-0                                  carlosedp/prometheus:v2.7.1
carlosedp/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.28.0
carlosedp/configmap-reload:v0.2.2
```

Is there an easy way to get the text to right align if the first column is empty?

**Update:**

I found one of the issues and updated the code to show how I am creating the array.  The command I was using to create the first array was adding a newline character.

After updating to remove the newline character the output now looks like this, so there isn't a case where there's an empty key, there are just cases where there are multiple values for a given key.

```sh
column1                               column2
prometheus-k8s-0                      carlosedp/prometheus:v2.7.1 carlosedp/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.28.0 carlosedp/configmap-reload:v0.2.2
```

Comment: Your edit show nothing ! Tell us how you got your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a perfect solution but I was able to get roughly the behavior I wanted by checking if the second column has more than one word, then splitting it and iterating over each string if it does.

```sh
for i in "${!associative_array[@]}"; do
    if [[ $(echo "${associative_array[$i]}" | wc -w) -gt 1 ]]; then
        for image in ${associative_array[$i]}; do
            printf '%s\t%s\n' "$i" "$image"
        done
    else
        printf '%s\t%s\n' "$i" "${associative_array[$i]}"
    fi
done) | column -t -x
```

Which produces the following output.

```
prometheus-k8s-0                      carlosedp/prometheus:v2.7.1
prometheus-k8s-0                      carlosedp/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.28.0
prometheus-k8s-0                      carlosedp/configmap-reload:v0.2.2
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just need to add a length specifier to the first `%s` in your `printf` call:

```
$ printf "%-50s%s\n" "$i" "${associative_array[$i]}"
```

Note that this gets rid of the tab character, which is no longer needed since the first column is now right-padded with spaces until it's 50 characters in length. Also, I chose `50` because that's the width of column 1 in your first two rows.

If you use this approach, you'll also want to remove the `| column -t -x` at the end, because it is now redundant, and will actually undo your `printf` formatting because it treats consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.

If your version of `column` supports it, you can also try leaving your `printf` as-is and instead using `column -t -x -s $'\t' -n`, which tells `column` to use `\t` as the delimiter, and to not treat multiple adjacent delimiters as a single delimiter:

```
$ printf "%s\t%s\n" column1 column2 foo bar "" baz | column -t -x -s $'\t' -n
column1  column2
foo      bar
         baz
```

And of course you can group some options and shorten

```
column -t -x -s $'\n' -n
```

to

```
column -txns $'\t'
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, but it is still producing the same output :/

Comment: @jmreicha That's because you're piping it to `column`, which undoes the formatting.

Comment: @jmreicha I've edited my answer to include a second solution which still uses `column`.

Comment: Hrm, something funky must be going on, after updating the script to use the additional `column` arguments I still seem to be getting the same output.

Comment: @jmreicha If you run the `printf` command from my answer directly on the command line, do you get the same output shown in my answer? (i.e. the command that prints foo, bar, and baz)

Comment: Yes I am able to print your example correctly.  I just cannot get my example to format correctly, so I think maybe there's something I'm missing.  I added a little bit more debug to the original post, let me know if there is any other information you think would be useful.

Comment: You may want to consider @ctac_'s answer. He spotted something I missed. There should be no way that you can be getting an empty string while iterating keys of an associative array. It looks like you have a *value* that contains newlines.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly don't work with an associative array.
You can't assign a emty key.
Try that and see what happen !

```
declare -A associative_array=( [one]=bar []=truc [three]=foo [four]=baz)
(printf "column1\tcolumn2\n"
for i in "${!associative_array[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$i" "${associative_array[$i]}"
done)
echo "number of items = ${#associative_array[@]}"

./script-bash.sh: line 1: []=truc: bad array subscript
column1 column2
four    baz
three   foo
one     bar
number of items = 3
```

Comment: I see.  I wonder if there is a way to handle the case then for empty keys?

Comment: @jmreicha If you need to be able to have empty keys, just add a fixed string to every key when you're populating the array, and then remove it again when you print it. Something like `array["x$key"]="$value"` for assigning, and then when you are iterating the array and want to print out the key, you can replace `"$i"` with `"${i#x}"`, which will remove the `'x'` from the beginning. But if you're expecting to have empty keys, you might want to consider whether an associative array is really the right way to implement your program. *Especially* if you might get multiple empty keys.

Comment: @jmreicha If you have multiple empty keys (or for that matter, any duplicate keys), each subsequent key/val pair where the key is empty (or is a duplicate of another key) will mean that you're overwriting the previous value, since each key must be unique, and an associative array will only store a single value for each unique key.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see part of the problem now.  The reason I was getting different output is because the command I was using to create the array was adding an extra newline character.  Working on updating original post with new info.

Comment: Updated original post with (hopefully) better details, it is a little more complicated than I thought although I don't think there is actually a case where there are empty keys. Maybe the better question for this might be, "how should I approach this problem without associate arrays"?